# Why does it say it is static when the method isn't static?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

I am attempted to make an object oriented stock system for a theoretical video shop.

I am constantly getting the following error message:

```
non-static variables xyz cannot be accessed from a static context.
```

All the info I have found on static contexts has been for when one method is static and the other is not, however none of my methods are static.

In this piece of code I get that error message twice and I don't understand why.

```
if (enterOption == 1) {
    Movie movieNew = new Movie (titleInput, yearInput, directorInput, ratingInput, genreInput);
    VideoShop.movies.add(movieNew);  
} else {
    UI.runUI();
}
```

I get it from `VideoShop.movies.add(movieNew);` and the `UI.runUI();` method call.

Full method:

```
public void createMovie ()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Title: ");
    String titleInput = sc.next();

    System.out.println ("Year: ");
    int yearInput = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println ("Director: ");
    String directorInput = sc.next();

    System.out.println ("Rating [G / PG / M / MA15 / R18]: ");
    String ratingInput = sc.next();

    System.out.println ("Genre [a - Action/ b - Drama/ c - Comedy/ d - Musical/ e - Family/ f - Documentary]: ");
    String genreInput = sc.next();

    System.out.println ("Format [VCD/DVD]: ");
    String formatInput = sc.next();

    System.out.println ("Cost: ");
    double costInput = sc.nextDouble(); 

    System.out.println ("Quantity: ");
    int quantityInput = sc.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Confirm?");
    System.out.println("1. Yes 2. No, return to main menu");

    System.out.println("Enter option: ");
    int enterOption = sc.nextInt();

    if (enterOption == 1) {
        Movie movieNew = new Movie (titleInput, yearInput, directorInput, ratingInput, genreInput);
        VideoShop.movies.add(movieNew);

    } else {
        UI.runUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please explain why i might be having this problem?

Comment: Are You using this in Your main()? Java's main is static...

Comment: Post your complete method.

Comment: I am not using the main method

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that `VideoShop.movies` is non-static field. Instead of using `VideoShop.movies` you should create an object:

```
VideoShop shop = new VideoShop();
shop.movies.add(movieNew);
```

The same for `UI`:

```
UI ui = new UI();
ui.runUI();
```